# Why are MMS single images sometimes displayed as videos?

Tags: android, mms

I wrote [a silly app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/rage-faces/com.idunnolol.ragefaces) that allows people to send preset images to users.  The app mostly works fine (as long as the user has an app that can handle MMS on their phone) but I've had some users complain that the MMSes show up on their phones as video rather than as an image.  The video ends up just being a single image, over the span of a few seconds.

The way that the code works, it copies the file to the SD card, which is then passed into the EXTRA_STREAM Intent extra.  I know that all the images are PNGs, and they're all sent with the type set to "image/png".  Yet somehow they end up as videos on the receiver's end.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong?  Is this the fault of the MMS application, or is there something I can do on my end?